# Why are the time limits in here?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I've hit two time limits:

- You cannot post two questions within 90 minutes

Okay, what if I hit two questions about different topics?  Why do I have to wait between them?

- You cannot accept your answer within 6 hours

Okay, I've found an answer to my own question because none of the other users cared enough or knew enough to provide theirs.  The answer solves my problem perfectly (because I'm the originator of the problem and I've found the solution, right?), and I want to leave note to posterity.  But no, it cannot be accepted.

These limits seem arbitrary to me and are very frustrating in their effects, causing me to not want to contribute.

Comment: These time limits are put in place to prevent spammers from filling up the site, and to encourage users to think / research a little before posting a new question, among other reasons.

Comment: What would happen if thousands of users started posting questions every minute? The site would be overrun. There wouldn't even be enough people to delete them - let alone answer them.

Comment: You should be asking one question per question, not two.

Comment: If you're needing to ask two questions on the site within 90 minutes you're probably in a situation where you're either in over your head (and ultimately need to go back to learning the fundamentals of what you're trying to achieve) or haven't searched well enough for answers to existing problems.

Comment: Of course the limits are arbitrary.  They need to be big enough to stop spammers but not so big as to deter askers.  What the best time is is subjective.

Comment: The delay on accepting your self answer to a question is to allow ample time for others to provide an answer as it is not always possible for an answer to be provided in a short time.

Comment: the question isnt really bad. its asking about functionality of this site. you guys can give answer instead of commenting and downvoting. dont downvote because the question seems stupid to you. and dont get blind when question is already downvoted. **I dont understand reason of -17**

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary try not to make rude assumptions about other people's motivations.

Answer (score 24):

Question rate limiting is in place for a few reasons.

- Spam. We want to ensure spammers can't post too much too quickly. When you have low reputation, we can't be sure if you're a spammer or a regular new user, but these restrictions lift as time goes on.
- Research. [We want you to research your question first!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) We get so many duplicates per day because people asked a question before searching; when you can't ask, you're encouraged to search, and you may actually find your answer before posting your question. **This is the desired outcome; Stack Exchange is designed purposefully with this in mind**.

> Turns out, slowing folks down just a little when it looks like they're getting off on the wrong foot is the most effective way to help potentially great users become great users. We don't go from 100 km/h straight into a wall any longer, [folks get a lot more help much sooner, when they need it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) Additional just-in-time help (triggered while writing a question) is in the works.
>
> New users who aren't doing so well initially will be shown the additional guidance and will be asked to wait anywhere from one to seven days before asking their next question, depending on how they've done recently.

Waiting to [accept your own self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is a little different. This is because:

- The reputation based system encourages users to reward **other users** for helping them. We want people to keep coming back, playing the game, and we want to encourage you to reward someone else *if* they've helped you.
- We want to ensure that there's time for answers to come in before a question is "accepted" and moved on. Perhaps you've come up with *one solution*, but maybe someone comes along with an *even better solution that you haven't thought of*. Perhaps this better solution takes some time to write up and explain. Give them that chance!
- Formerly, you used to not be able to accept your own answer *at all*. See [Jeff Atwood's answer on this subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6045/200235) and the [corresponding blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).
- I should also mention that it's [not actually discouraged to self answer your own questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), quite the opposite in fact. The time limit is simply to ensure that others have times to weigh in, too.