# Aren't new users throttled asking questions anymore?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users, rate-limiting

How can this happen:

> [image]

I thought that new users were throttled with asking no more questions than [one within 90 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256323/questions-are-now-rate-limited-to-1-per-90-minutes)?

As [@gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat) stated in [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore#comment339351_322157):

> since all the garbage they dumped is deleted now, here's user profile to help moderators and SO developers investigate this bug: [MBall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277410/mball)

Comment: Oh that one.  I'm going to have dreams about that poster tonight.

Comment: since all the garbage they dumped is deleted now, here's user profile to help moderators and SO developers investigate this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6277410

Comment: @MartinJames I saw you flagged it. But how did the second question make it in at all?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ indeed:(

Comment: [status-bydesign]

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå status by design is [90 minutes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256324/839601) rate limit for new users asking questions at Stack Overflow. One thing that could possibly break it is, they recently implemented [cross-site posting rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278000/165773) - and these new limits use network-wide default (something laughable like 5 or 10 minutes). If done wrong, cross-site limits could override those at Stack Overflow

Comment: Oh - someone took down the wards, and the creatures from the lowest levels of hell are breaking through to our dimension:(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Not mine, so watch out, there's a troll about..

Comment: @gnat Why the `<kbd></kbd>` edit? Does that improve something actually?

Comment: [yes, improves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138594/do-images-need-a-border-around-them). A while ago I've been using quote formatting for similar effect but someone at MSE convinced me that kbd works better (eg on mobile)

Comment: @gnat OKI DOKE. (okily dokily)

Comment: Is this a person who created a new account because their original account was deleted or suspended?  Because the account @gnat linked to only contains two deleted questions, and I don't see how any system could be crafted to throttle on fewer questions than that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey _"Is this a person who created a new account because their original account was deleted or suspended? "_ Within 5 minutes? The questions were both active before deletion.

Comment: Within 5 minutes of what?  You still need *two* questions to detect a pattern.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't get you? My question is how these two questions could appear within a timespan of 5 minutes, and OP wasn't blocked to ask the latter one?

Comment: If the OP was blocked as you described, you wouldn't see two questions appear, you would only see one.  You need at least two questions to be asked and heavily downvoted to detect a pattern of abuse.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, but I've seen two questions within 5 minutes (as captured in the screen shot). Why actually?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  I've heard of the 90 minute rate limit on new users before, but have never been confident that it actually works that way.  I assume that rate limiting only comes into play if a pattern of abuse is detected.

Comment: @RobertHarvey _"but have never been confident that it actually works."_ Well, there's a number of complaints appearing frequently on Meta SO, that seem to improve it actually works.

Comment: What?  How do you complain about something that is actually working?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant complaints on Meta like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305683/why-are-the-time-limits-in-here or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316158/asking-more-than-one-question-in-less-than-90-minutes

Comment: Yep, looks like it's broken.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, you're a hard nut to crack :-P ...

Comment: It just seems unlikely that such a simple rate limiter would be broken, unless someone at SE tripped over a power cord.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But _I've been observing it_. And it wasn't the 1st time recently. That was just a sample I was able to catch, and decided to report here.

Comment: hmm I wouldn't be surprised if broken rate limit helped quite a bit in bootstrapping [recent voting ring](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322115/839601). Generally the way how SE developers approach the rate limit looks backward to me: network wide default should be like at SO ie 90 minutes (not these senseless 5-10) and only sites that requested it lowered would have lower rate limit than default

Comment: I seem to recall a post about new user rate limiting can be worked around by posting from multiple IP addresses but I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259942/1773867 + answer below that

Comment: [Another recent example.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321428/176646)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot THX for backing up.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sorry about that. I'd hoped the *other* rate-limits we'd built in over the past couple of years would pick up the slack here, but... That didn't quite happen.

Here's a handy graph of users who hit the new-user asking limit per week, by week:

[image: too image, didn't view: the number dropped like the proverbial rock]

And here's a corresponding graph of users who hit the question-block, just so you can see that there's no real slack-picking-up happening here:

[image]

Oops.

I've put in a change request to restore the ability to customize this limit network wide; if all goes well, that'll be available again in another couple of weeks.

*Until then,* here's what I'm gonna try:

1. The new-user ask limit is now one question every **40** minutes, *network-wide.* That means only 1 question every 40 minutes on Stack Overflow, but also means you'd need to wait 40 minutes after asking a question on, say, Woodworking to ask a related question on Crafting or Home Improvement. And yes, gnat, it also means you'd need to wait 40 minutes after asking a question on Stack Overflow before asking a question on Programmers.
2. [Rolling rate-limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773) kick in faster. Like, *immediately*. If your first question is downvoted and you try to ask another one 40 minutes later, you'll be forced to wait at least a day. That's potentially very harsh... But probably also better than penalizing *everyone* for the behavior of a few. We'd always intended rolling rate-limits to supplant the new-user rate-limits, and this will hopefully allow them to do so.

Why 40 instead of 90 or at least 60? Because there's *no* ability to customize this per-site right now, and because this applies to all new users from a given IP, this may be very painful for small or niche sites. I picked 40 because 75% of questions scoring <0 asked in the past 30 days got their first downvote within 39 minutes, so this should allow the rolling rate-limits to kick in for most users without requiring per-site overrides.

Of course, anyone caught circumventing either of these restrictions will still have their account and questions unceremoniously deleted and their network blocked from asking further questions for a generous period of time.

Sorry again for not catching this sooner; please let me know if you notice any odd unintended consequences here.

Comment: Well, thank you. _"Because there's no ability to customize this per-site right now,  ..."_ That explains a lot.

Comment: "I picked 40 because 75% of questions scoring <0 asked in the past 30 days got their first downvote within 39 minutes" heck, that's awesome. I need more data about that, I mean, I meant to ask for it, but, you know, effort... and university

Comment: Would this be worth placing in MSE so that legitimate users that *might* encounter this would have some idea of what's going on?  I know we've got the lion's share of users, but the smaller sites would definitely be confused about this.

Comment: Probably just worth answering that question when it arises, @Makoto. Lemme know if you see one.

Comment: how this system is supposed to work if user is established at site A ([say, Math](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow/7826#comment24674_7826)) but new at site B (say, Programmers)? Would they be rate limited on site B? would they be rate limited network wide?

Comment: Everywhere *except* Math, @gnat.

Comment: Maybe worth updating [your MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277485/implement-cross-site-posting-rate-limits-to-slow-down-spammers/278000#278000)? /cc @Makoto

Comment: @ShadowWizard FWIW I updated [rate limiting guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/165773) and [features changelog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272544/165773)

Comment: Thanks @gnat though better have the answer up to date as well.

Comment: they say [rate limit is 90 minutes now](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/318884/perl-variable-not-interpretted-correctly#comment676446_318884 "'I wasn't allowed to post for another 90 minutes'") not 40 - at least for reposting from Programmers to Stack Overflow (not that I complain)

Comment: Looks like "in another couple of weeks" was accurate for once, @gnat - functionality was restored on May 13th.

Comment: so network wide rate limit works about like this - the asker who (like in my example) dumped garbage at Programmers will be able to repost at SO in 90 minutes, and in case if they decide to start with their trash at SO, they will be able to repost at Programmers in 40 minutes, do I understand this correctly? And at both sites, if their first question is voted down and closed in the meantime, rolling rate limit at that site will give them full day to think about how to do better next time, right?

Comment: Something like that, @gnat. I don't *think* the rolling rate-limit thing is set to 1 question anywhere outside of SO right now, but apart from that yeah it should work that way - essentially the time of your last question (anywhere) is cached and compared against the wait-threshold *for the current site* when a new user goes to ask a question.

Comment: looks like indeed 1 question triggers rate limit only at Stack Overflow. [This user at Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/230822/lawrence-cyber) has just tested that - despite getting their question closed and heavily downvoted they were able to dump yet another one 40 minutes later (with predictable results)

Comment: `Here's a handy graph of users who hit the new-user asking limit per week, by week` eh. Here is a better picture: http://highlighthollywood.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/the_watchers_on_the_wall_by_88grzes-d7lo859.jpg?w=573

Comment: Shog, I just observed [new user](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/254718/praditio-aditya) posting questions at a rate less than 40 minutes ([screen shot says first question was "37 mins ago" and second "2 min ago"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLY7g.png)), did something change?

Comment: No, there's a bit of a hole in the logic there, @gnat; occasionally someone slips through.

Comment: understood, thanks for explaining!

Comment: With the growing use of NAT by home ISPs in countries with a proportionally small allocation of IPv4 addresses, has Stack Exchange made the business decision to create a poor user experience for new users in those countries?

Comment: Shog one recent [incident](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49372415#49372415) made me wonder if system counts only for downvotes and ignores closures, do you by chance remember if this is so? User managed to reask an hour after their first question was closed, and the only plausible reason seems to be that it has got no DVs to trigger rate limit (unfortunately couldn't see timings of downvotes to make a more accurate check)

Comment: I'm being hit by the 40 minute rule on japanese.stackexchange.com just now. I was a member there since 2015 (without asking any questions). I've been a member on SE in general since 2010, with hundreds of posts on different sites. Isn't it unreasonable to count me as a "new user" for the purpose of spam prevention?

Comment: Naw; spammers got wise to the whole, "create pile of accounts & let 'em age before use" trick years ago, @max - actual activity is the only reliable metric.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense and I agree that just the ownership of multiple accounts for years should be irrelevant. But the high number of questions/answers or rep on other sites of StackExchange, why are those insufficient to treat me as an established user? In other words, why is the determination of "new user" based on posts/rep on a single site, rather than the entire StackExchange?

Comment: That would indeed be a good check to make, @max. When these checks were originally implemented, doing cross-site activity checking wasn't feasible; it would be now.

Comment: Are the jump in May 2014 and dip in September 2014 real? If so, is it known what caused them (or at least some correlation with some events)?