# 90-minute question wait enforced between sites

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

Having earlier today posted a question on a sister SE site, and now having a SO-appropriate question I wrote it out... only to be hit by the 90-minute question latency blocker.

Not as a complaint, but mostly to express surprise, why is it that these limits are enforced over multiple fields of knowledge? There being only limited overlap between certain communities, I could not seeing having a per-field posting limit to be a bad thing?

EDIT: Also, I now immediately find out that the rate-limiter for Meta is separated. Any particular reason for that? At least it proves that it is technically possible.

Comment: Because spammers cross post spam over multiple sites. Meta requires 5 rep to post so does not require so much spammer rate limiting.

Comment: [Here's the MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277485/implement-cross-site-posting-rate-limits-to-slow-down-spammers) from where it was implemented. It's a new thing, the cross-site rate limit. As Robert said, it was implemented to stop spammers.

Comment: @RobertLongson it is more likely that after feature to set per-site rate limit was recovered time of posting this question [at meta satisfied network-wide requirement of 40 min limit while SO-specific limit of 90 minutes was not yet met](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore#comment347445_322265)

Answer (score 13):

This was implemented [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277485/implement-cross-site-posting-rate-limits-to-slow-down-spammers) as a response to a spammer tactic to spam the same tosh on many many different SE sites at the same time, allowing them to create sometimes 10 or 11 posts before the system and the community moderation blocks them. This was remedied by a new shared lockout across sites for new questions.

This restriction will ease off as you participate more, and should not bother you for long.