# Does the question rate-limit get lower with reputation?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I am wondering if the time limit on asking questions ever lowers. Like if you get a certain amount of reputation, does the limit change from 1 every 90 minutes to something such as 1 every 30 minutes? Or does it stay the same to keep spamming impossible? If so, I think a feature should be added where if you have a certain amount of reputation, you should be able to post more frequently.

Comment: Have you tried posting well-received answers? If you give something back to the community, you may discover rate-limiting does not apply anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Please refer to [The Complete Rate-limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900):

> ### Asking
>
> - Users < 125 rep, [40 minutes, network-wide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601)
>
>   - Users limited by [Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610), one question per week
>   - Users limited from asking questions for 1 - 7 days [based on the performance of their previous
>       questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)
> - Users < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
> - Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds
> - On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Math (not active on all other sites)
>
>   - maximum of 6 questions per day
>   - [maximum of 50 questions per 30 days][10]
>
>     > Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period

Note that it's 40 minutes network-wide, but 90 minutes on Stack Overflow, until you reach 125 reputation.