# Do new users get temporary additional restrictions if their first question is heavily downvoted and/or closed?

Tags: support

Recently, a new user had their post heavily downvoted. They mentioned in the comments that, when they went to create a new question to replace that one based on feedback in the comments, the system said that they couldn't post for three days. I was a little baffled by that but didn't get a chance to ask about it; are some kind of restrictions put in place for new users whose first question is heavily downvoted and/or closed?

Comment: From the main Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/248731

Comment: "Like, _immediately_. If your first question is downvoted and you try to ask another one 40 minutes later, you'll be forced to wait at least a day..." ([Aren't new users throttled asking questions anymore?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they do. The exact details of this are secret (and painfully hard to explain even if it wasn't; there's like a *formula* here, where the exact nature of the restriction isn't known until the user actually tries to post)... But the gist of it is, if your first question is poorly-received, you'll probably be asked to wait a day before asking another one, and given a bunch of advice on both asking better questions *and* fixing your existing question.

If you ignore that advice, the time you have to wait between questions increases as you continue to ask poorly-received ones, until eventually you have to wait 6 months between questions.

There are other restrictions that can come into play as well: folks from networks that've recently sent a lot of dodgy stuff our way might be limited to 1 post per day *regardless* of how that post is received, while folks who've posted a lot of crap and then deleted their accounts will tend to come back with training wheels bolted on for convenience.

Comment: I think I understand why answerers needn't be throttled as strongly as askers but [activity of this user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/269626/superuser?tab=answers) suggests that current rate limiting for answerers may be a bit too weak

Comment: Can "poorly received" include either heavy downvotes or having your question put on hold? If a question is only heavily downvoted (but not closed) or is only put on hold (but isn't heavily downvoted), will either of those result in the temporary restrictions?

Comment: They can, @EJoshuaS; I'm gonna be a little bit cagey as to the weights given to each, but it's safe to say that neither *helps*.