# Does this constitute a "gibberish post"?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, rude-or-abusive

I'm asking about the following question: [VB.NET Quick Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313339/vb-net-quick-sort)

And an image (in case the question is deleted, so this question still makes sense):
[image]

The OP deliberately obfuscated the code by posting it as ASCII code. The question was downvoted and put on hold for obvious reasons. Does this constitute a "gibberish post"? Can/should it be flagged as rude/abusive based on being gibberish?

The text you see at the top is literally the only readable text here - the rest is the wall of gibberish you see in the blockquote.

Comment: And non-hex ASCII at that!

Comment: Interesting: `097`... someone is not aware of C octal literals?

Comment: It just doesn't matter.  Please step aside, it might splatter a bit.

Comment: I guess it's one of the "smarter" students who know that professors might find their code posted on stackoverflow :)

Comment: He must think we're all Jon Skeet.

Comment: Seriously though, let's call Jon maybe he can help the kid.

Comment: Did anybody bother to untangle the ridiculous ASCII just to see why the code was so bad that it had to wear a brown paper bag over its head?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I don't think so, the comments were pretty clear with the OP that no one was going to decipher that and that if he wanted an answer he needed to post the code in a readable form.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit After decoding (`perl -ne 'print map { chr } split'`), it looked like a pretty straightforward attempt at a Quicksort implementation. Nothing incredibly awful or weird.

Comment: @duskwuff I'm slightly baffled as to why he did that to begin with, actually

Comment: So he figured how to convert it and all that, but couldn't do a sort? (Baffled) - By the way, it's gone.

Comment: @DaniSpringer I did figure that it would be deleted soon enough, especially once I posted on Meta (which is why I included the image for us lesser mortals with less than 10K rep). I'm a little baffled about that, too, actually (or why he even bothered to obfuscate it at all).

Comment: Yup I saw you wrote that. :) Personally, I think users should need _much more_ rep to do what we can do. Sad... You work for a day to write the best question you can, 5 guys drop by while sipping their morning coffee, and your account goes bye bye.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, that is not gibberish. It is *obfuscated* at best.

Rude/abusive flags should not be used if it is their first offense, specially because they come with a penalty when enough people follow your flag.

Instead these posts should be closed for being unclear or lacking an MCVE. Use a down vote to indicate that the post has severe issues and isn't useful in its current state.

There is not much value in keeping it around , so once closed it can be deleted by 20K-ers, unless the OP decides to edit their post into shape before the final delete vote is casted.

Comment: "*specially because they come with a penalty when enough people follow your flag.*" But... I think any person who posts that question *should* be penalized. It's not that they found some obfuscated code and posted it; they *deliberately obfuscated* it. There's no way someone could do that and *not* be genuinely malicious.

Comment: @NicolBolas added first offense then. I assume good faith when an OP leave comments. It is strange that they don't comply to our requests, still not abusive enough in my book.

Comment: @NicolBolas Would "trying to make this un-Google-able so as to avoid attention from a professor, interviewer or boss" count as malicious? Misguided and counter-productive, yes, but definite possibilities.

Comment: @PaulRoub: Perhaps not malicious towards us, but it certainly suggests [mens rea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea) of some form.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have marked a rude/abusive flag helpful on this one. As @Nicol said, this was not an innocent error. At best, it was a question posted in a deliberately difficult-to-read form. At worst, it was cheating, simple trolling, or otherwise malicious. Regardless, it was deliberate, and not welcome.

Comment: @EdCottrell If I know my flag will be handled by you I'm happy to give that a try but I also have to deal with the other mods who might have slightly different criteria. When not clear cut and if the community can handle it I rather take that save route, or use an additional custom mod flag if I feel mod attention is needed anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas I tend to agree - it seems like there *should* be penalties for that kind of behavior - at a minimum it seems like a question ban (beyond what's ordinarily imposed for asking a beyond [the usual penalties for asking a bad first question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348414/do-new-users-get-temporary-additional-restrictions-if-their-first-question-is-he).