# Must wait 40 minutes between asking questions (But first question was deleted)

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Consider the following scenario:

I asked a question on one Stack Exchange site (DBA.StackExchange), and then realized it was not the appropriate site and asked the same question on Server Fault. Even though I deleted the first question, I am forced to wait 40 minutes to ask the same question again on the appropriate site.

Is this the desired behavior for this specific situation? I'm assumed this will impact Stack Overflow as well.

Edit: This question differs from [Aren't new users throttled asking questions anymore?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157) in that I wanted to know if deleting a new question from one Stack Exchange site and asking a question in another Stack Exchange site should be allowed.

Comment: @gnat Possibly.  My question was ultimately answered below, but the question involved throttling between sites, and the throttling between sites while also taking deletions into account.

Comment: @gnat I can see "Loosely related" but definitely not duplicate.

Comment: "The new-user ask limit is now one question every 40 minutes, network-wide. That means only 1 question every 40 minutes on Stack Overflow, but also means you'd need to wait 40 minutes after asking a question on, say, Woodworking to ask a related question on Crafting or Home Improvement..."

Comment: @gnat that is the announcement(?) of the change, it doesn't answer the question here. More importantly, not all answers to that question are equally answers to this question, nor are all answers to this question equally answers to that question. That question _is_ loosely related to this question, it _is not_ a duplicate.

Comment: In "Is this the desired behaviour", *this* refers to behaviour coming from 
DBA.StackExchange going to Server Fault. You don't ask anything about behavior on Stack Overflow, and only provide a reference to it about you being assumed (?) it impacts here as well. Why post a question here? In its current form it should go on Server Fault's meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes

This is the desired behavior for this specific situation. If you're rate limited from asking a question, but can delete your question, ask a new one, then undelete the original, it would kind of negate the point.

See also: **[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)**

Comment: "Yes this is desired" by whom? I'm not even convinced it works that way. Most if not all of the limits in the "complete rate limiting guide" are certainly per site not combined limits for all sites on the network.

Comment: @MartinSmith if you're rate limited from asking a question, but can delete your question, ask a new one, then undelete the original, it would kind of negate the point, no? As for the network-wide-ness of it, see the first line under the "Asking" heading in the linked post: _"Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network"_

Comment: Yep good point. Hadn't thought of that undelete avenue.

Comment: @TinyGiant You are absolutely correct. Obviously a little frustrating, but I've since gone on to answer my own question. I guess the one would need to weigh the benefit of this policy against the cost which is less questions asked and answered.

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper given the rather massive amount of questions that Stack Overflow receives in a day, and the fact that such rate limiting has been in place for quite a while, I'd say the policy is correctly weighted.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's very true. Honestly I am not a big fan of a lot of SO policies, but my question was specifically about whether or not this was desired community behavior and to that, you have answered my question :)